# <pe:documentViewer> isn’t loading pdf file in Liferay 6.2 environment

Tags: primefaces-extensions

<pe:documentViewer> isn’t loading pdf file in Liferay6.2 environment. Using following code
<pe:documentViewer height="475" url="#{Myjavabean.pdfFilePath}" />

Getting following error Msg:

PDF.js v1.5.188 (build: 0e2d50f)

Message: file origin does not match viewer's

I am using Primefaces-6.2.RC2.jar and primefaces-extensions-6.1.1.jar

I checked pdf file location on linux server and it is being created there successfully but not loading on browser. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am pretty sure that error is in the PDF code that if the URL you are calling is not the same as the URL of your website it won't work.  Its basically saying you can't load a URL from someone else's site.  Using the Streaming mechanism of DocumentViewer instead.